# GA4 Track Total Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to track Revenue with the new GA4 but i'm having a hard time understanding how.
[Show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcquI.png)

Can anyone please help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The "value" parameter in tagging populates the "Revenue" metric in reports. For example if you upload the purchase event from this example (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce#purchase):

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  affiliation: 'Google Store',
  coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
  currency: 'USD',
  items: [{
    item_id: 'SKU_12345',
    item_name: 'jeggings',
    coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
    discount: 2.22,
    affiliation: 'Google Store',
    item_brand: 'Gucci',
    item_category: 'pants',
    item_variant: 'black',
    price: 9.99,
    currency: 'USD',
    quantity: 1
  }, {
    item_id: 'SKU_12346',
    item_name: 'jeggings',
    coupon: 'SUMMER_FUN',
    discount: 2.22,
    affiliation: 'Google Store',
    item_brand: 'Gucci',
    item_category: 'pants',
    item_variant: 'gray',
    price: 9.99,
    currency: 'USD',
    quantity: 1
  }],
  transaction_id: 'T_12345',
  shipping: 3.33,
  value: 21.09,
  tax: 2.22
})
```

Then, GA4 will show a Total Revenue of $21.09.

[image: Homepage total revenue]

In the Monetization Overview Report, GA4 will show this $21.09 is specifically categorized as Ecommerce revenue.

[image: Monetization overview]

Comment: If I modify the original purchase event(for example changing the event name based on other sent parameters) it will be recognized as conversion but will not populate the total revenue column, why?